# trying to create a virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, path, virtual-environment

I typed "pipenv install" into the powershell in the correct directory and now it has given me a huge error message that i think has something to do with my python path. The error message is displyed below.

A list of my sys.path is:

'c:\Users\f l a s h\Documents\pythonfile',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages',
'C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages'

I need this because I'm going to use it for learning django. Any help on what this is or how to fix it would be great.

```html
PS C:\Users\f l a s h\Dev\cfehome> pipenv install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 618, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 105, in get_python_version
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 233, in install
    retcode = do_install(
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1920, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 350, in find_a_system_python
    return next(iter(finder.find_all_python_versions()), None)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 312, in find_all_python_versions
    python_version_dict = getattr(self.system_path, "python_version_dict", {})
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 120, in system_path
    self._system_path = self.create_system_path()
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 82, in create_system_path
    return pyfinder_path.SystemPath.create(
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 682, in create
    instance = instance._run_setup()
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 233, in _run_setup
    new_instance = new_instance._setup_windows()
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\path.py", line 411, in _setup_windows
    windows_finder = WindowsFinder.create()
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 146, in create
    return cls()
  File "<attrs generated init pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 113, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 430, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/f l a s h/anaconda3/python.exe'
PS C:\Users\f l a s h\Dev\cfehome> pipenv --python 3.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 618, in parse_executable
    result_version = get_python_version(path)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\utils.py", line 105, in get_python_version
    c = subprocess.Popen(version_cmd, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1236, in invoke
    return Command.invoke(self, ctx)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\f l a s h\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 199, in cli
    ensure_project(
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 576, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 354, in find_a_system_python
    python_entry = find_python(finder, line)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\utils.py", line 2213, in find_python
    result = finder.find_python_version(line)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 276, in find_python_version
    if os.name == "nt" and self.windows_finder is not None:
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\pythonfinder.py", line 129, in windows_finder
    self._windows_finder = WindowsFinder()
  File "<attrs generated init pipenv.vendor.pythonfinder.models.windows.WindowsFinder>", line 13, in __init__
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\windows.py", line 113, in get_versions
    versions[py_version.version_tuple[:5]] = base_dir
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 365, in __getattribute__
    result = super(PythonVersion, self).__getattribute__(key)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 430, in version_tuple
    self.patch,
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 375, in __getattribute__
    instance_dict = self.parse_executable(executable)
  File "c:\users\f l a s h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\pythonfinder\models\python.py", line 620, in parse_executable
    raise ValueError("Not a valid python path: %r" % path)
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/f l a s h/anaconda3/python.exe'
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163642/how-to-pass-directory-path-that-have-space-to-windows-shell or maybe having a user name with spaces isn’t a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install pipenv:

```
$ pip install --user pipenv
```

If you're trying to install a package using pipenv:

```
$ cd myproject
$ pipenv install <package_name>
```

[docs.pipenv.org](https://docs.pipenv.org/install/#installing-pipenv)

But according with the last line in your log:

```
ValueError: Not a valid python path: 'C:/Users/f l a s h/anaconda3/python.exe'
```

You have installed anaconda3 and you're using python.exe from there. Take in count that pipenv and anaconda3 are different way to create environments and they are not necessarily compatibles.

If you're going to use Anaconda3 you can use 'conda' command to install your packages.

```
$ conda install <package_name>
```

[Conda Managing environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-envs)

[Conda cheatsheet](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/cheatsheet.html)

If you're going to use pipenv for your project, you can check your PATH environment variable to see from where you are calling python executable file and change it to use your local own installation of python instead of Anaconda3 python.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely to have some stale entries of previously installed pythons in the registry.

see this:
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4334